# Dynamically passing selected options to subsequent form using PHP/AJAX/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to dynamically pass selected options from a form to a second form but am having trouble as to exactly how to do that as my first AJAX is a POST type and my jQuery is a click event.  Maybe I shouldn't be using jQuery to do the second piece but I was having trouble only using AJAX so I tried this method.  Essentially I want to select options such as a winner and a loser of a match and then process bonuses for in-match scoring.  Here is how the page looks when you select the first most basic type of match...

[initial screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrNQq.gif)

Then when I click the Add InMatch button, a row is added for bonus scoring...

[button clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMHpv.gif)

The problem then becomes that I cannot get the selected options from the first screen to be available as options when the Add button is clicked. How exactly would I make sure that when I click that button, the selected options in the winner/loser boxes is available in the new list of options?

This is my AJAX function to display different initial options depending on the match selection...

```
$("#matchtype").change(function() {
    var match = $(this).val();
    if(match != "") {
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"scorer.php",
        data:{match_id:match},
        //async: true,
        success:function(response) {
          var resp = $.trim(response);
          $("#matchtypename").html(resp);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#matchtypename").html("NOT FOUND!");
    }
});
```

And then this is my jQuery function to add the bonus options...

```
jQuery(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    jQuery('button.addinmatch').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        counter++;

        var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td>In-Match Scoring' + counter + ':</td><td><select name=\"inmatchwrestler' + counter + '\"><option value=\"NONE\">Select Wrestler</option></select><select name=\"inmatch' + counter + '\"><option value=\"NONE\">Select In-Match Scoring Option</option><option value=\"finisher\">Finisher</option><option value=\"pinfall\">Pinfall</option><option value=\"dq\">DQ</option><option value=\"co\">Count Out</option><option value=\"nc\">No Contest</option></select></td>');

        jQuery('table.matchscoringtable').append(newRow);

    }); });
```

Finally, this is the relevant parts of the HTML/php file that work with the AJAX/Query (scorer.php)...

```
<!-- where the AJAX changes the options depending on match type selection... -->
<tr id="matchtypename">       
</tr>



          <br><br>
<!-- the button the jQuery uses to add the bonus options -->
          <tr><td><button class="addinmatch">Add InMatch Option</button><br></td></tr>
```

And the php function that is called when singles match is selected...

```
function singles_match() {

        //echo "<tr>";
        echo "  <td>Match Result:</td>";
        echo "  <td>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchwinner\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Winner</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchloser\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Loser</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchhow\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select How the Match was Won</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"finisher\">Finisher</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"pinfall\">Pinfall</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"dq\">DQ</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"co\">Count Out</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"nc\">No Contest</option>";
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "  </td>";
/*      echo "  </tr><br><br>";
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "  <td>In-Match Scoring 1:</td>";
        echo "  <td>";
        echo "      <select name=\"inmatchwwrestler\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Wrestler</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchhow\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select In-Match Scoring Option</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"finisher\">Finisher</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"pinfall\">Pinfall</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"dq\">DQ</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"co\">Count Out</option>";               
        echo "          <option value=\"nc\">No Contest</option>";
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "  </td>";*/

}
```

EDIT: Full html...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Scorer</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

function drop_down() {

    $strSearch = "SELECT name FROM Roster ORDER BY name asc";
    $sqlResult = mysql_query($strSearch);

    while($arrayRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlResult)) {
        $item = $arrayRow[name];
        echo "<option value=\"$item\">$item</option>\n";
    }   
}

function singles_match() {

        //echo "<tr>";
        echo "  <td>Match Result:</td>";
        echo "  <td>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchwinner\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Winner</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchloser\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Loser</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchhow\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select How the Match was Won</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"finisher\">Finisher</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"pinfall\">Pinfall</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"dq\">DQ</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"co\">Count Out</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"nc\">No Contest</option>";
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "  </td>";
/*      echo "  </tr><br><br>";
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "  <td>In-Match Scoring 1:</td>";
        echo "  <td>";
        echo "      <select name=\"inmatchwwrestler\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Wrestler</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchhow\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select In-Match Scoring Option</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"finisher\">Finisher</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"pinfall\">Pinfall</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"dq\">DQ</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"co\">Count Out</option>";               
        echo "          <option value=\"nc\">No Contest</option>";
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "  </td>";
*/      //echo "  </tr>";

}

function tag_match() {

        //echo "<tr>";
        echo "  <td>Match Result:</td>";
        echo "  <td>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchwinner1\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Winner 1</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchwinner1\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Winner 1</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchloserq\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Loser 1</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchloser2\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Loser 2</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchhow\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select How the Match was Won</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"finisher\">Finisher</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"pinfall\">Pinfall</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"dq\">DQ</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"co\">Count Out</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"nc\">No Contest</option>";
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "  </td>";
        echo "  </tr>";
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "  <td>In-Match Scoring 1:</td>";
        echo "  <td>";
        echo "      <select name=\"inmatchwwrestler\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Wrestler</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchhow\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select In-Match Scoring Option</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"finisher\">Finisher</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"pinfall\">Pinfall</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"dq\">DQ</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"co\">Count Out</option>";               
        echo "          <option value=\"nc\">No Contest</option>";
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "  </td>";
        //echo "  </tr>";

}

function triple_match() {

        //echo "<tr>";
        echo "  <td>Match Result:</td>";
        echo "  <td>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchwinner\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Winner</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchloser1\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Loser 1</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchloser2\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Loser 2</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchhow\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select How the Match was Won</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"finisher\">Finisher</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"pinfall\">Pinfall</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"dq\">DQ</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"co\">Count Out</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"nc\">No Contest</option>";
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "  </td>";
        echo "  </tr>";
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "  <td>In-Match Scoring 1:</td>";
        echo "  <td>";
        echo "      <select name=\"inmatchwwrestler\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Wrestler</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchhow\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select In-Match Scoring Option</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"finisher\">Finisher</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"pinfall\">Pinfall</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"dq\">DQ</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"co\">Count Out</option>";               
        echo "          <option value=\"nc\">No Contest</option>";
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "  </td>";
        //echo "  </tr>";

}

function handicap_match() {

        //echo "<tr>";
        echo "  <td>Match Result:</td>";
        echo "  <td>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchwinner1\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Winner 1</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchwinner2\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Winner 2</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchloser1\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Loser 1</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchloser2\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Loser 2</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchhow\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select How the Match was Won</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"finisher\">Finisher</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"pinfall\">Pinfall</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"dq\">DQ</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"co\">Count Out</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"nc\">No Contest</option>";
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "  </td>";
        echo "  </tr>";
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "  <td>In-Match Scoring 1:</td>";
        echo "  <td>";
        echo "      <select name=\"inmatchwwrestler1\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Wrestler 1</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"matchhow\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select In-Match Scoring Option</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"finisher\">Finisher</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"pinfall\">Pinfall</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"dq\">DQ</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"co\">Count Out</option>";               
        echo "          <option value=\"nc\">No Contest</option>";
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "  </td>";
        //echo "  </tr>";

}

function add_in_match_scoring_option($inmatchnum) {
        //echo "  </tr>";
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "  <td>In-Match Scoring $inmatchnum:</td>";
        echo "  <td>";
        echo "      <select name=\"inmatchwrestler$inmatchnum\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select Wrestler</option>";
                        drop_down();
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "      <select name=\"inmatch$inmatchnum\">";
        echo "          <option value=\"NONE\">Select In-Match Scoring Option</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"finisher\">Finisher</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"pinfall\">Pinfall</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"dq\">DQ</option>";
        echo "          <option value=\"co\">Count Out</option>";               
        echo "          <option value=\"nc\">No Contest</option>";
        echo "      </select>";
        echo "  </td>";

}


//MySql DB Info
include("../includes/db.php");



if (isset($_POST['card']) OR isset($_POST['schedule']) OR isset($_POST['submitmatch']) OR isset($_POST['start']) OR isset($_POST['results']) OR isset($_POST['finished']) OR isset($_POST['finalize']) OR isset($_POST['grand']) OR isset($_POST['open']) OR isset($_POST['close']) OR isset($_POST['finishedcard']) OR isset($_POST['match_id'])) {


<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitmatch'])) {
        //Nothing for now
    } elseif (isset($_POST['match_id'])) {
        $matchtype = $_POST['match_id'];

        if ($matchtype == "singles") {
            singles_match();
        }

        if ($matchtype == "tag") {
            tag_match();
        }

        if ($matchtype == "triple") {
            triple_match();
        }

        if ($matchtype == "handicap") {
            handicap_match();
        }

    } /*elseif (isset($_POST['addinmatch'])) {

        $inmatchnum += 1;
        add_in_match_scoring_option($inmatchnum);           

    }*/
    else {          

    include("../includes/sidebar.php");

    ?>

      <p align="center">
      <font size=5><b>Control Panel</b></font><br>
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
        <table class="matchscoringtable">
          <tr> 
            <td>Show:</td>
            <td><input type="Text" name="ppv" size="30" value="<?php echo $show ?>"> 
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td style="height: 30px">Match Number:</td>
            <td style="height: 30px"><input type="Text" name="matchnum" size="10" value="<?php echo $matchnum + 1; ?>"> 
            </td>
          </tr><!--
          <tr> 
            <td>Match Type:</td>
            <td><select name="matchtype">
                <option value="REGULAR">Regular Match</option>
                <option value="DOUBLER">Doubler</option>
                <option value="BONUS">Bonus Points</option>
                <option value="TIEBREAKER">Tiebreaker</option>
              </select>
              Doubles Match # / Bonus Points 
              <input type="Text" name="doublebonus" size="1"></td>
          </tr>
-->
          <tr> 
            <td>Match Description Line 1:</td>
            <td><input type="Text" name="matchdesc1" size="70"><br>*** Make sure to only put match participants on this line. ***</td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td>Match Description Line 2:</td>
            <td><input type="Text" name="matchdesc2" size="70"><br>*** Enter any special stips or title matchs here (i.e. Cage Match or WWE Champsionship). ***</td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td>Match Type:</td>
            <td><select name="matchtype" id="matchtype">
                <option value="NONE">Select a Match Type</option>
                <option value="singles">Singles Match</option>
                <option value="tag">Tag Team Match</option>
                <option value="triple">Triple Threat Match</option>
                <option value="handicap">Handicap Match</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <br><br>
          <tr id="matchtypename">
          </tr>       
          <br><br>
          <tr><td><button class="addinmatch">Add InMatch Option</button><br></td></tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type="Submit" value="Submit Match" name="submitmatch">
        Adds / Updates this match based on Match Number <br>
        <br>
        <input type="Submit" value="Save Card" name="finishedcard">
        Submit all matches first, this does not submit a match
      </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax_.js"></script>
      <!--<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Enter PPV Card" name="card">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input name="closedate" type="text" id="closedate" value="Close Date">
        <br>
        <input name="closetime" type="text" id="closetime" value="Close Time">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Open Registration" name="open">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Close Registration" name="close">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enter PPV Results" name="results">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Update Grand Championship" name="grand">
        <br>
        <font size="1">press when results are final (take a look for any scoring 
        issues or messed up tiebreakers before pressing)</font><br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Close PPV" name="finalize">
        <br>
        <font size="1">simply closes the &quot;current&quot; PPV. Press when you 
        want to start a new PPV. You will have to sign back in though.</font><br>
        <hr>
        <br><font size="2">
        PPV Name<br>
        <input type="text" name="newppvname">
        <br>
        <br>
        PPV Date<br>
        <input type="text" name="newppvdate">
        <br>
        YYYY-MM-DD<br>
        <br>
        PPV Season<br>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_current_season($fed); ?>" name="newppvseason">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Pay-Per-View" name="schedule">
        <br></font>
      </form>
-->   <br></p>
      <?php
    }

}
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT2: Full ajax_.js

```
$("#matchtype").change(function() {
    var match = $(this).val();
    if(match != "") {
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"scorer.php",
        data:{match_id:match},
        //async: true,
        success:function(response) {
          var resp = $.trim(response);
          $("#matchtypename").html(resp);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#matchtypename").html("NOT FOUND!");
    }
});

jQuery(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    jQuery('button.addinmatch').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        counter++;

        var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td>In-Match Scoring' + counter + ':</td><td><select name=\"inmatchwrestler' + counter + '\"><option value=\"NONE\">Select Wrestler</option></select><select name=\"inmatch' + counter + '\"><option value=\"NONE\">Select In-Match Scoring Option</option><option value=\"finisher\">Finisher</option><option value=\"pinfall\">Pinfall</option><option value=\"dq\">DQ</option><option value=\"co\">Count Out</option><option value=\"nc\">No Contest</option></select></td>');

        jQuery('table.matchscoringtable').append(newRow);

    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by this: _...the selected options in the winner/loser boxes is available in the new list of options_? Please provide an extended explanation for that.

Comment: It is almost impossible to help you, if you don't give us the whole page codes. We need them to test, you know? So, instead of cutting them in pieces in order to explain them to us, just give us the whole page codes. Don't worry, we can read them. And write the file name of each file for which you are presenting the whole code.

Comment: Sorry...added the full files.

Comment: To answer this question --- "What do you mean by this: ...the selected options in the winner/loser boxes is available in the new list of options?" --- if I choose Person 1 for the winner and Person 2 for the loser, I want those options to appear as choices in the InMatch options I dynamically am adding.  That's all I meant,

Comment: So, you have only one PHP file and one js file for the question's task?

Comment: What is the file name here: _EDIT: Full html..._ ?

Comment: The main php/html file is scorer.php. The Ajax/jQuery file is ajax_.js

Comment: Ok. I asked because I saw _wwe_advanced_scorer3.php_. But you corrected, so it's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never perform an ajax request with the target "url" being the same as the page from which the ajax request is performed. In your code, you are running the ajax request on a control ("matchtype") in the *scorer.php*, with *scorer.php* as the "url" property of the ajax request as well. When the ajax is performed, the results are indeed fetched, but the whole content of *scorer.php* is replaced by them. E.g. the whole control panel with the table "matchscoringtable" disappears. Therefore, the container in which the results should be added ("matchtypename") is not there anymore. In short, I decided to change the whole code structure of yours, having in mind that, imho, would be better for your project.

I strongly advise you to not output any html code from the php code. So, no more `echo '<div>...</div>'`. Find solutions to avoid this kind of design, which is very hard to maintain.

I strongly advise you to use either the *mysqli* extension (the object-oriented version of it, not the procedural one), or, even better, the PDO extension, for data access. Because the *mysql* extension was already removed as of php 7.0.0.

I suggest you to learn and use the [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/) css framework, in order to provide a very beautiful design and page structure. With this future step of yours in mind, I did not use a table, as you did, but only divs. Bootstrap does not use tables. Instead, it uses divs to build a so called *grid*. Anyway, Bootstrap is 100% worthy, easy and fun to learn.

You said: *if I choose Person 1 for the winner and Person 2 for the loser, I want those options to appear as choices in the InMatch options I dynamically am adding*. I still didn't understand what you meant by *to appear as choices in the InMatch options*. Therefore I made so, that, when "Add InMatch Option" button is clicked, the selected winner and the selected loser are appended as "option" tags to the *inMatchWrestlerXX* combobox. If it's not what you wanted, you can easily change it to fit your needs.

I hope you'll understand my code. Note that I used my naming and coding conventions. Start with *scorer.php*. Then go to *custom.js*. From there follow the code road. In principle, you can run my code as it is. All pages reside at the same directory level.

#### scorer.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <!-- CSS resources -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- JS resources -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="page-container">

            <div class="messages">
                Here appear the error/success messages ...
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="matchType">Match Type:</label>
                <select id="matchType" name="matchType">
                    <option value="">Select a Match Type</option>
                    <option value="singles">Singles Match</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div id="matchTypeContent" class="form-group">
                Here appears the content upon the match type selection ...
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" id="addInMatchOptionButton" name="addInMatchOptionButton" class="add-in-match">
                    Add In-Match Option
                </button>
            </div>

            <div id="inMatchOptions" class="form-group"></div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### custom.js

```
var inMatchCounter = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#matchType').change(function () {
        var matchType = $(this).val();
        var matchTypeLabel = $('#matchType option:selected').text();

        resetMessages();

        if (matchType !== '') {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                url: 'matchTypeContent.php',
                data: {
                    'matchType': matchType,
                    'matchTypeLabel': matchTypeLabel
                },
                success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $('#matchTypeContent').html(response);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    handleAjaxError(jqXHR);
                },
                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    //...
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#matchTypeContent').html('');
        }
    });

    $('#addInMatchOptionButton').click(function () {
        var matchWinnerId = $('#matchWinner').val();
        var matchLoserId = $('#matchLoser').val();

        resetMessages();

        if (matchWinnerId === '') {
            displayMessage('warning', 'Please select a match winner.');
            return false;
        }

        if (matchLoserId === '') {
            displayMessage('warning', 'Please select a match loser.');
            return false;
        }

        inMatchCounter++;

        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: 'inMatchOption.php',
            data: {
                'matchWinnerId': matchWinnerId,
                'matchLoserId': matchLoserId,
                'inMatchCounter': inMatchCounter
            },
            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#inMatchOptions').append(response);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                handleAjaxError(jqXHR);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                //...
            }
        });
    });
});

/**
 * Display a user message.
 * 
 * @param type string Message type: success|danger|warning.
 * @param message string Message.
 * @return void
 */
function displayMessage(type, message) {
    $('.messages').html('<div class="message ' + type + '">' + message + '</div>');
}

/**
 * Reset messages.
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function resetMessages() {
    $('.messages').html('');
}

/**
 * Handle an error raised by an ajax request.
 * 
 * If the status code of the response is a custom one (420), defined by 
 * the developer, then the corresponding error message is displayed. 
 * Otherwise, the displayed message will be a general user-friendly 
 * one - so, that no system-related infos will be shown.
 * 
 * @param jqXHR object The jQuery XMLHttpRequest object returned by the ajax request.
 * @return void
 */
function handleAjaxError(jqXHR) {
    var message = (jqXHR.status === 420)
            ? jqXHR.statusText
            : 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again.';

    displayMessage('danger', message);
}
```

#### custom.css

```
html,
body,
button {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
}

select {
    font-size: 14px !important;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}

.page-container {
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.messages {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.message {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.success {
    color: #3c763d;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
}

.danger {
    color: #a94442;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
    background-color: #f2dede;
}

.warning {
    color: #8a6d3b;
    border-color: #faebcc;
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
}

form {
    width: 400px;
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-group label {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100px;
}

button {
    padding: 7px 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    background-color: #8daf15;
}
```

#### functions.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Get the players.
 * 
 * @return array The players list.
 */
function getPlayers() {
    //@todo Fetch from database.
    return array(
        3 => 'Susan',
        19 => 'Jules',
        //...
    );
}

/**
 * Get a player name by player id.
 * 
 * @return string The player name.
 */
function getPlayerName($playerId) {
    //@todo Fetch from database.
    switch ($playerId) {
        case 3:
            $playerName = 'Susan';
            break;
        case 19:
            $playerName = 'Jules';
            break;
    }

    return $playerName;
}
```

#### matchTypeContent.php

```
<?php

// Validate the match type.
if (!isset($_POST['matchType']) || empty($_POST['matchType'])) {
    /*
     * This custom response header triggers the ajax error because the status 
     * code begins with 4xx (which corresponds to the client errors). Here is
     * defined "420" as the custom status code. One can choose whatever code 
     * between 401-499 which is not officially assigned, e.g. which is marked 
     * as "Unassigned" in the official HTTP Status Code Registry. See the link.
     * 
     * @link https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml HTTP Status Code Registry.
     */
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 No match type provided.');
    exit();
}

$matchType = $_POST['matchType'];
$matchTypeLabel = $_POST['matchTypeLabel'];

switch ($matchType) {
    case 'singles':
        require 'matchTypeSingles.php';
        break;
    case 'tag':
        // require 'matchTypeTag.php';
        break;
    //... and so on ...
    default:
        break;
}
```

#### matchTypeSingles.php

```
<div>Match Result (<?php echo $matchTypeLabel; ?>):</div>

<select id="matchWinner" name="matchWinner">
    <option value="">Select Winner</option>
    <?php require 'playerOptions.php'; ?>
</select>

<select id="matchLoser" name="matchLoser">
    <option value="">Select Loser</option>
    <?php require 'playerOptions.php'; ?>
</select>

<select id="matchHow" name="matchHow">
    <option value="">Select How the Match was Won</option>
    <option value="finisher">Finisher</option>
    <option value="pinfall">Pinfall</option>
    <option value="dq">DQ</option>
    <option value="co">Count Out</option>
    <option value="nc">No Contest</option>
</select>
```

#### playerOptions.php

```
<?php
require_once 'functions.php';

foreach (getPlayers() as $id => $name) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <?php echo $name; ?>
    </option>
    <?php
}
```

#### inMatchOption.php

```
<?php
require_once 'functions.php';

// Validate the match winner's id.
if (!isset($_POST['matchWinnerId']) || empty($_POST['matchWinnerId'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 No match winner provided.');
    exit();
}

// Validate the match loser's id.
if (!isset($_POST['matchLoserId']) || empty($_POST['matchLoserId'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 No match loser provided.');
    exit();
}

// Validate the in-match counter.
if (!isset($_POST['inMatchCounter']) || empty($_POST['inMatchCounter'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 No in-match counter provided.');
    exit();
}

$matchWinnerId = $_POST['matchWinnerId'];
$matchLoserId = $_POST['matchLoserId'];
$inMatchCounter = $_POST['inMatchCounter'];
?>

<div>In-Match Scoring <?php echo $inMatchCounter; ?>:</div>

<select name="inMatchWrestler<?php echo $inMatchCounter; ?>">
    <option value="">Select Wrestler</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $matchWinnerId; ?>"><?php echo getPlayerName($matchWinnerId); ?> (winner)</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $matchLoserId; ?>"><?php echo getPlayerName($matchLoserId); ?> (loser)</option>
</select>

<select name="inMatch<?php echo $inMatchCounter; ?>">
    <option value="">Select In-Match Scoring Option</option>
    <option value="finisher">Finisher</option>
    <option value="pinfall">Pinfall</option>
    <option value="dq">DQ</option>
    <option value="co">Count Out</option>
    <option value="nc">No Contest</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks dakis.

Comment: One question I did have tho: short of adding a hidden element to inMatchOption.php to store the $inMatchCounter, is there another way or a better way to make that available on the scorer.php?  Right now the $_POST['inMatchCounter'] isn't available to scorer.php and since the name of the inMatchWrestler dynamically adds the inMatchCounter number to the inMatchWrestler --- i.e. inMatchWrestler1 and so on --- scorer.php doesn't know how many inMatchWrestlers there are.  If I had a count, I could loop through up to the count and do it that way.

Comment: @ChrisL. You are welcome. The _inMatchCounter_ and _inMatchWrestler_ remain something abstract for me, since you didn't presented an extensive explanation about them. But, as I see it now, the _inMatchCounter_ is already available to _scorer.php_: the global _inMatchCounter_ js variable, changed by each click on _addInMatchOptionButton_. If you wish, you can instead define a hidden input in _scorer.php_ to hold the counter value incremented/decremented by the _addInMatchOptionButton_.

Comment: That's my fault as I forgot to explain it; essentially, the idea is you fill out all the fields and then will press a submit button at the bottom that will write the scores to the mysql database.  When that happens, the $_POST['inMatchCounter'] is NULL.  After testing your rewrites, I then went to impement my form and added the button.  When I did a vardump, I wasn't seeing the inMatchCounter value anymore.  I guess maybe I shouldn't do it that way and should instead use the method you used with the AddInMatch button.

Comment: @ChrisL. Chris, I would love to help you, but the counter thing is not only a line of code. It requires multiple places were it has to be implemented, changed and read. And I can not do much more for you, because I would not only have  to see all your codes, but also to understand the whole logical scheme of your website. That's why I gave you the solution in my previous comments (global js variable, or hidden input). You'll have to find out by yourself, how and where the counter should be coded.

Comment: @ChrisL. Or I can recommend you to ask another question on stackoverflow, focused on exactly the task of counter, with code, explanations, element/page names.

Comment: No worries.  I know how to solve it but wasn't sure what I am doing is considered the right way.  I took this over from someone else and it's a lot of code in many files which needs to be re-done IMO but it was kind of I stepped in an emergency situation and just never got around to re-doing it.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help and detailed responses.

Comment: @ChrisL. You are welcome. For the future, keep in mind, that a usual form submitted through a submit button refreshes the whole page, or redirects to another one. That way you can "preserve" values (like a counter) only by placing them in form controls (like hidden inputs). On the other hand, an ajax request refreshes only a part, or parts of a page. Its advantage is not only that the values in form controls will be "preserved" (without the need of a form tag, actually), but previously set global js values can maintain their state, as well... Good luck.